# $2 + 2 = 5$ (Fake proof, or ?)

Tags: arithmetic, fake-proofs

Basically, there is no error in the following steps(as it seems), but there **is** some error due to which **2 + 2 = 5**. What is it?

```
                      -20 = -20
                    16-36 = 25-45
             16-36+(81/4) = 25-45+(81/4)
(4^2)-(2*4*9/2)+((9/2)^2) = (5^2)-(2*5*(9/2))+((9/2)^2)
              (4-(9/2))^2 = (5-(9/2))^2
                  4-(9/2) = 5-(9/2)
                        4 = 5
                      2+2 = 5
```

Comment: $x^2=y^2$ does not necessarily imply that $x=y$. Not to meantion $(5^2)-(2*5*(9/2))+((9/2)^2)\neq (5+(9/2))^2$ anyways.

Comment: This is an old and easy trick. A hint is "sign".

Comment: You've gotten $(4-\frac92)^2=(5-\frac 92)^2$ which isn't strange

Comment: Taking roots on both sides of $(4-(9/2))^2=(5-(9/2))^2$ you get $|4-(9/2)|=|5-(9/2)|$. The rest should be obvious.

Comment: For future posts visit https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to properly display functions.

Comment: The third from last step is correct: $\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$. The step after that step is incorrect.

Comment: Also please consider learning to typeset using MathJax.

Comment: It's as if you wrote $(-2)^2=(2)^2\implies{}$$-2=2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint -

$a^2-2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2\ne(a+b)^2$

This is your mistake.

Also $x^2=y^2$ doesn't imply that $x=y$ is the only possibility.

It should be $|x|=|y|$.

Comment: I corrected it, still, that's not what I want

Comment: What if we take square roots on both sides?

Comment: There is difference in things. Suppose $x=\sqrt9$ then $x=3$. If $x^2=9$ then $x=\pm3$.

Comment: Deepesh  $\sqrt{x^2} = |x| \neq x$, as Kanwaljit notes above,

Comment: So if $x^2=y^2$, we have different cases.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot that :-P

Comment: Your answer is inaccurate. By saying "doesn't mean that $x=y$ only", you are actually implying "not only $x=y$ *but something else as well*". Instead you should say "doesn't **necessarily** imply $x=y$" or "doesn't imply that $x=y$ is the only **possibility**".

Comment: @user21820 sometimes I am unable to write things properly. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh: You're welcome. Your answer is now good! =)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is when you go from a quadratic to a linear.

$$(4-\frac{9}{2})^2 = (5-\frac{9}{2})^2$$
$$|4-\frac{9}{2}| = |5-\frac{9}{2}|$$
$$|\frac{-1}{2}| = |\frac{1}{2}|$$
$$\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$4-\frac92=\pm\left(5-\frac92\right)$$ so that

$$4=5\lor4+5=\frac92+\frac92$$ and the world is safe...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

$$a^2=b^2 \implies |a|=|b|$$

That is :

$$a=b ~~\text{or}~~ a=-b$$

> Therefore $$\Big(4-\frac{9}{2}\Big)^2=\Big(5-\frac{9}{2}\Big)^2$$ $$\implies \Big|\Big(4-\frac{9}{2}\Big)\Big|=\Big| \Big(5-\frac{9}{2}\Big) \Big|$$ $$\implies 0.5=0.5$$ Which is absolutely correct.